# VSC выдает ошибку в пути к файлу

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Когда я запускаю свой python код, то VSC пропускает только заглавную букву "А" в пути к файлу, остальную кириллицу он не трогает (раньше всё было нормально)[image: вот скриншот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на ваш путь к файлу. Он содержит кириллицей только один каталог - "Андрей". Именно здесь программа некорректно обрабатывает код. Исправьте на латинский алфавит, например: Andrey. Должно помочь.

У меня такая же проблема. Только каталогов много. Только что разобрался.

Плохо понимаю, как это работает, но все команды идут через PowerShell. Если запустить PowerShell, то можно легко проверить Вводятся ли в командную строку заглавные русские буквы.

Если да, то это наш случай. Дело в багованном пакете PSReasLine.

Чтобы починить, нужно его переустановить:

1. `Remove-Module PSReadLine`
2. Удалить папку C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadLine
3. `Install-Module PSReadLine`